# Ayuda con este codigo no se quitarle la coma al ultimo elemento a este ciclo

Tags: php

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < $cuenta) {

        $actualizaInfoActualizar.= '$'.$campos[$i].', ';
        $i++;       
}
```

quiero quitar la (,) que se genera en el ultimo elemento, los demas están bien.

Answer (score 4):

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < $cuenta) {

        $actualizaInfoActualizar.= '$'.$campos[$i].', ';
        $i++;       
}

$actualizaInfoActualizar = rtrim($actualizaInfoActualizar,",");
```

Ahí está compadre.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes controlar cuando sea el último elemento escribir sin coma.

```
$i = 0;

    while ($i < $cuenta) {
            if($i == ($cuenta-1)){
                $actualizaInfoActualizar.= '$'.$campos[$i];   
            }else{
                $actualizaInfoActualizar.= '$'.$campos[$i].', ';
            }
            $i++;       
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta, hacer un [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php), una vez termine el bucle:

```
 $actualizaInfoActualizar = substr($actualizaInfoActualizar,0,-1);
```

Y ya estaría. Espero que te sirva :)